# The elif wont work when I try it and this wont work when it worked in my last code

Tags: python

```
year_born = input('what year were you born? ')
year = (2019)
age = (year - int(year_born))
if age <= 18:
  if age <= 65:
    print('Here is your pensioners ticket.')
  print('Here is your child's fare ticket.')
else:
  print('here is your ticket.')
```

I tried and elif statement on "if age <= 65:" but it shows syntax error. this works in my last code bellow. so i'm not for sure what is wrong or what I could do to make this work correctly. the problem with this is it does not initiate the "print('Here is your pensioners ticket.')". thanks for the help love you all.

```
first_name = input('first name only: ')
if len(first_name) >= 5:
  if first_name[-1] == 'a':
    print('you won $1000!!')
  else:
    print('you did not win $1000')
else:
  print('you did not win $1000')
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: how exactly it is when I put it in format but it wont when i post??

Comment: Indent your code then check for where you are forgetting to type cast

Comment: You are making `year` a `tuple`, is there a reason for this?

Comment: @jab `(2019)` is not a tuple, `(2019,)` would be.

Comment: Correct, my mistake

Comment: I think you've confused `<` for `>`... If someone's age is less than 18, it's obviously less than 65, no need to check.

Comment: You logic is off; a pensioner should be someone with age *greater* than 65, which cannot be someone whose age is less than 18.

Comment: @KianAlford what is the result of running this code, if not printing “here is your pensioners ticket”? What did you input when asked “what year were you born”?

Comment: i did this the other way so did not work in age 18 the opposite the the correct one. dont know why but.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely at `print('Here is your child's fare ticket.')` because you use `'` without escaping it. Possible solutions:

```
print('Here is your child\'s fare ticket.')
```

Or

```
print("Here is your child's fare ticket.")
```

The way I would approach it:

```
year_born = input('what year were you born? ')
year = 2019
age = (year - int(year_born))
if age <= 18:
    print('Here is your child\'s fare ticket.')
elif age >= 65:
    print('Here is your old person ticket.')
else:
    print('here is your general adult ticket.')
```

Comment: @KianAlford well that was the syntax error, so clearly you did not properly fix it, or there were multiple errors. You can even see it is the error in your post because the text changes colors when it thinks the string is over.

Comment: @KianAlford No problem. We all started somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From a logic standpoint you want prisoners to be 65+ and children are 18 and below. Otherwise they get a regular ticket. If this is correct then I would use the following:

```
year_born = int(input('what year were you born? '))
year = 2019
age = year - year_born

if age >= 65:
    print('Here is your pensioners ticket.')
elif age <= 18:
    print('Here is your child\'s fare ticket.') #need to escape the backslash here btw
else:
    print('here is your ticket.')
```

As for the other code you want to check the last letter first, then see if the length is above 5:

```
first_name = input('first name only: ')

if first_name[-1] == 'a':
    print('you won $1000!!')
else:
  print('you did not win $1000')
```